# Nginx proxy several domains to different ports

Tags: nginx, debian, virtualhost

I have a server with nginx listening to port 80 and has configs for several domain names, connections to which should be proxied to different ports.

Here are my config files:

**domain1**

```
#This is for redirecting everyone from www.domain.com to domain.com
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name www.domain1.com;

    return 301 $scheme://domain1.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        server_name domain1.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

**domain2**

```
#This is for redirecting everyone from www.domain.com to domain.com
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name www.domain2.com;

    return 301 $scheme://domain2.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        server_name domain2.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8090/;
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

**domain3**

```
#This is for redirecting everyone from www.domain.com to domain.com
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name www.domain3.com;

    return 301 $scheme://domain3.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        server_name domain3.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8091/;
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

All these config files are (as usual) located in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and symlinked to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

When i added first file everything worked as a charm, when i added second file it is the same, after adding third file nginx stopped giving me any messages when i try to do `service nginx reload` or `service nginx restart` or `service nginx start`.

It responds to `service nginx stop` and `service nginx status`. Apparently these functions work, but other functions in these preconditions are not responding and do not do anything. The output below is just copy-paste from my console.

```
# service nginx status
[ ok ] nginx is running.
# service nginx reload
# service nginx restart
# service nginx stop
[ ok ] Stopping nginx: nginx.
# service nginx start
# service nginx status
[FAIL] nginx is not running ... failed!
#
```

If i remove symlink to the third file everything works perfectly again.

So here is the question -- is it something wrong with my setup? or my logic? or with nginx?

The environment is:

```
- Debian Squeeze x64
- Nginx version 1.2.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the symptoms you're having indicate that your nginx config with the 3th file is incorrect, which is why the reload is failing

The output of `nginx -t` should tell you where in your config the problem is.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot. Actually the problem there was with `server_name` directive, where i tried using wildcard improperly.